# R to Python pandas numpy.where conversion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

what is the best way to write the following R code in Python (pandas dataframe) using numpy.where syntax.

```
Data$new = ifelse(Data$Diff > 1.652*Data$Diff10, 1,
                         ifelse(Data$Diff < 3.95*Data$Diff10, -1, 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Data['new'] = np.where(Data['Diff'] > 1.652*Data['Diff10'], 1,
              np.where(Data['Diff'] < 3.95*Data['Diff10'], -1, 0 ))
```

EDIT:

It seems code above have logic error, because never return `0`.

Maybe need:

```
Data = pd.DataFrame({'Diff':[2,4,.5],
                   'Diff10':[1,1,1]})

print (Data)
   Diff  Diff10
0   2.0       1
1   4.0       1
2   0.5       1

Data['new'] = np.where(Data['Diff'] < 1.652*Data['Diff10'], 2,
              np.where(Data['Diff'] > 3.95*Data['Diff10'], 3, 4 ))

print (Data)
   Diff  Diff10  new
0   2.0       1    4
1   4.0       1    3
2   0.5       1    2
```

Comment: Works. Appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you swap `>` and `<`, so I add working solution, where both conditions are `False` in last row. Please check edited answer.